# Extruder motor doesn't pull filament during job only

Tags: marlin, troubleshooting, extruder, ramps-1.4, underextrusion

I have a weird problem over here, I'm restoring an FLSUN Kossel Mini (with a RAMPS 1.4 board) and it printed fine for the last two days.

Now when I initiate a print job, the extruder motor doesn't push filament into the nozzle ( it retracts filament like it's supposed to, it just doesn't push.) and this only happens during a print job.

- I cleaned the nozzle
- Increased/decreased printing temp.
- Swapped motor drivers.
- Adjusted Z offset.
- Reset the motherboard.
- Changed acc and jerk values.

None of these did the trick for me, and when I manually control the extruder motor (from the LCD or Repetier) it pushes the filament without any problems.

Comment: Is it turning at all? Are there signs of filament grind? Does it fail from the start or at some point during the print?  Is coldside hot?..

Comment: Yes it turns fine, and the whole extruder assymbly is clean from any grind or debris.

Comment: The extruder doesn't pull filament from the start of the job, but weirdly enough it retracts the fillament when z hopping.

Comment: Are you sure you are sending good gcode? And have you tried to remove hotend altogether, to make sure it has no part in the issue?

Comment: Yes I did, first I used the didcated extruder buttons on repetier then tried with G1 commands, and both seemed to move the stepper motor fine.

Comment: Another thing I noticed was fillament wasn't extruded on the first 3 layers, when the print job reaches layer 4 the extruder motor returns to pumb fillament.

Comment: I eleminated the clogging/jaming possibility by romoving the filament wire and starting a print job.

Comment: This is when I found about the 3 layers problem.

Comment: Can the extruder stepper be damaged in this case?

Comment: Extruder motor works or it does not. It's not layer dependent. It seems your works. Check hour hcode